# Notebook wireless network disabled on startup (sometimes)

Tags: wireless, lenovo

My notebook sometimes starts with the wireless network disabled, then I have to turn it off and on again to go back.

Lenovo Ideapad 310
Ubuntu Mate 18

[image]

Can I solve this definitively?